# My sudoku solver python code is not being excecuted

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm following TechWithTim on the Sudoku Solver with Backtracking, and my code won't exec. here is the code:

```
board = [
    [7,8,0,4,0,0,1,2,0],
    [6,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,9],
    [0,0,0,6,0,1,0,7,8],
    [0,0,7,0,4,0,2,6,0],
    [0,0,1,0,5,0,9,3,0],
    [9,0,4,0,6,0,0,0,5],
    [0,7,0,3,0,0,0,1,2],
    [1,2,0,0,0,7,4,0,0],
    [0,4,9,2,0,6,0,0,7]
]

def print_board (bo):

    for i in range (len(bo)):
        if i & 3 == 0 and i != 0:
            print('- - - - - - - - - - - - -')

            for j in range(len(bo[0])):
                if j & 3 == 0 and j != 0:
                    print(' | ', end='')

                if j == 8:
                    print(bo[i][j])
                else:
                    print(str(bo[i][j]) + ' ', end='')
                    
print_board(board)

def find_empty(bo):
    for i in range(len(bo)):
        for j in range(len(bo[0])):
            if bo[i][j] == 0:
                return (i, j) #row, col
```

I have no clue why it's not working. I've tried everything, re downloading Python, using Pycharm instead of VSCODE, but yet no luck. In his video, it did work, and it even worked on the first part.
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqUwSA0xI-s&t=911s) is the link of the video.

Comment: How is the program being called?

Answer (score 0):

You used `&` instead of `%`. `&` is bitwise and, while `%` is modulo which is the operator you need here. Replace `if i & 3 == 0 and i != 0:` with `if i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:`.

Note : I might have missed other occurrences of this mistake. you shouldn't use `&` anywhere in this code so replace all of them with `%`.